# extract a string with a string quote issue pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, quote

I used the function below to extract a string from a character string in input,the issue is that when i put a string character with a string quote i can't extract it 
exp as input :

`AA015streetl'adeuilAB00201AC0041234AD012XXXXXXXXXXXXAE009TTTTTTTTT`

```
FUNCTION get_string (p_name    IN               VARCHAR2,
                     p_strg    IN               VARCHAR2,
                     p_len    OUT NOCOPY        PLS_INTEGER,
                     p_value  OUT NOCOPY        VARCHAR2)
        RETURN PLS_INTEGER
    IS
        v_counter   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
        v_strg       VARCHAR2 (4096) := SUBSTR (p_strg, 5);
    BEGIN
        p_value := NULL;
        p_len := 0.;

        WHILE v_counter < LENGTH (v_strg)
        LOOP
            IF SUBSTR (v_strg, v_counter, 3.) = p_name
            THEN
                p_len :=
                    TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (v_strg, v_counter + 3., 3.));
                p_value :=
                    SUBSTR (v_strg, v_counter + 6., p_len);
                RETURN (declaration_cst.ok);
            END IF;

            v_counter :=
                  v_counter
                + 6.
                + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (v_strg, v_counter + 3., 3.));
        END LOOP;

        RETURN (declaration_cst.nok);
            END;
    END get_string;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - are you saying you can't pass the string into the function when it has a single quote in it, or are you saying the output of the function is not correct?

More details on the issue you're experiencing, please.

Comment: Hi,I means the output of the function is not correct when it has a single quote in the string in input

Comment: not correct in what way? What were you expecting to see and what was actually output?

Comment: Your counting and offset logic seems quite messed up; are you saying this works with a value that doesn't have a quote in it? I don't see how it could.

Comment: Unless your example string doesn't match what you really pass, of course; the code implies you have five characters at the start you throw away, and then each block of data starts with a three-char name (not two-char). If you get the string format wrong it will error unless you look for the first field. Please show how you're actually calling this, with a working and a not-working example, and the output from both. I'd guess you're passing it with the wrong count, e.g. `AA016street...` from your example. We aren't mind readers though, so show us what you're really doing.

Comment: Hi the target is to extract Tags: AB for exemple, i used my function like this:FUNCTION get_string ('AB',
                     'AA015street l'adeuilAB00201AC0041234AD012XXXXXXXXXXXXAE009TTTTTTTTT',
                     p_len,
                     p_value  );
The target is to have p_len=002 and p_value=01 wich is doesn't work with the input AA

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but your code doesn't match the example string format.

Comment: I realize that this is probably a homework assignment, but if not you might want to know that [Oracle supplies the INSTR function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions073.htm#SQLRF00651) which accomplishes the same task that you seem to be trying to do. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

For the example string you showed, the substring offsets and counter adjustments in your code are off. This can extract any of the 'tags':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_string (p_name IN VARCHAR2, p_strg IN VARCHAR2,
    p_len OUT NOCOPY PLS_INTEGER, p_value OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2)
RETURN PLS_INTEGER IS
    v_counter PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
    p_value := NULL;
    p_len := 0;

    WHILE v_counter < LENGTH (p_strg)
    LOOP
        IF SUBSTR (p_strg, v_counter, 2) = p_name
        THEN
            p_len := TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (p_strg, v_counter + 2, 3));
            p_value := SUBSTR (p_strg, v_counter + 5, p_len);
            RETURN declaration_cst.ok;
        END IF;

        v_counter := v_counter + 5
            + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (p_strg, v_counter + 2, 3));
    END LOOP;

    RETURN declaration_cst.nok;
END get_string;
/
```

Your version was losing the first four characters completely in the `v_strg` assignment, and was then adjusting as if the tags were three characters, not two.

With a test block like:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
  str varchar2(256) := q'[AA015street l'adeuilAB00201AC0041234AD012XXXXXXXXXXXXAE009TTTTTTTTT]';
  len pls_integer;
  value varchar2(256);
  rc pls_integer;
begin
  rc := get_string('AB', str, len, value);
  dbms_output.put_line('AB -> ' || rc ||':'|| len ||':'|| value);
end;
/
```

and changing the 'AB' tags this gets:

```
AA -> 0:15:street l'adeuil
AB -> 0:2:01
AC -> 0:4:1234
AD -> 0:12:XXXXXXXXXXXX
AE -> 0:9:TTTTTTTTT
AF -> 1:0:
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6823a/1) with wrapper function so the extracted tag info can be shown more easily.

It doesn't make any difference if the string value contains a single quote, as long as the tag length is correct - it's just another character to substr and won't be interpreted any differently.

As Bob Jarvis mentioned, there are other ways to achieve this breakdown, but that's even more beyond the scope of what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a single-quote embedded in a string literal you're trying to pass to a function or procedure you'll need to double it (i.e. type two single-quotes instead of one) so that PL/SQL interprets it correctly. The doubled single-quote will be sent to the function as just one single quote, as you intend, but this is how single-quotes in literals are handled in PL/SQL. Thus, instead of calling your function as

```
n := get_string ('AB', 
                 'AA015streetl'adeuilAB00201AC0041234AD012XXXXXXXXXXXXAE009TTTTTTTTT', 
                 p_len,
                 p_value );
```

you should double the single-quote in the second parameter:

```
n := get_string ('AB', 
                 'AA015streetl''adeuilAB00201AC0041234AD012XXXXXXXXXXXXAE009TTTTTTTTT', 
                 p_len,
                 p_value );
```

If you're reading the input from a file or some other external source you don't have to do this; it's only necessary when a string **literal** has a single-quote in it.

Share and enjoy.